# Word for the person who drives the train

Tags: word-request

What is the specific name given to the person who drives the train? Is there any other way of calling the name despite calling them as engineer or engine driver?

Comment: [Railroad engineer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railroad_engineer)

Comment: A friend of mine is an engineer and his grandmother could not understand how that meant he could do anything other than drive a train.  What more proof do you need?   :-)

Comment: @fixer1234  Here's the rest of the proof needed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lNULzA8AOxY

Comment: We'll also use the term _conductor_ in Canada.

Comment: The engineer operates the train; the conductor is responsible for managing other aspects of the train's operation.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductor_(rail).

Answer (score 2):

The more common use is a **Railroad engineer**.

Which is an engineer (in America and Canada), engine driver, loco pilot, motorman, train driver (in Britain), is a person who operates a train. The driver is in charge of, and responsible for driving the engine, as well as the mechanical operation of the train, train speed, and all train handling.

[Source.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railroad_engineer)

Answer (score 1):

This does depend what country you are in. In Britian, we call them *train drivers*. In America, they are *engineers* or *railroad engineers*. They've also been called *engine drivers* and *locomotive engineers*, in the past in different places.